Godox TT600 triggering via cable driven from Arduino
May I use an Arduino microcontroller to fire a Godox TT600 by a cable?
I am using this device to trigger remotely a DSLR camera.
This Arduino fires a relay, which controls the cable.Gid

In theory you can, since the flash as a 3.5mm socket for this (appears to be the "mono" kind).
However, if you trigger both the camera and the flash from the Arduino you may have to figure out a delay between the two, otherwise the flash could fire before the shutter is fully open (which is sort of automatic when the flash is fired by the camera).

Both the camera and the flash are triggered by completing a ground circuit. You would just need to connect the trigger (relay) to the flash's 3.5mm sync port in parallel with the camera.
